# Should entities always be simple and mapped?

Tags: c#, coding-standards, entity-framework, clean-architecture

I am told everywhere that entities are only to represent the data structure, then entities should be mapped to a model and then the model possibly to a DTO.
The other way is similar, DTO -> model -> entity.

It seems simple, but when it comes to working on a lot of highly nested entities, it is very tedious to track changes, edit and delete them.

On the other hand, working on entities and using the change tracking that EF provides(in my case) is great. If I change, add or delete any nested entities, everything is represented perfectly when saved.

Always this mapping basically one to one, seemed to me a lot of work, which in most cases is unnecessary.

So, my design is in the Clean Architecture style. I modeled it the Ardalis way. My entities are in the style of Rich Domain Models.

But maybe I misunderstood his intentions?

E.g. here: [Github-1](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Clean.Architecture.UseCases/Contributors/Update/UpdateContributorHandler.cs)

Ardalis works on an entity, which it then directly saves.

Although I try to keep such business logic in domain services as he did here: [Github-2](https://github.com/ardalis/CleanArchitecture/blob/main/src/Clean.Architecture.UseCases/Contributors/Delete/DeleteContributorHandler.cs)

Or is it that saving nested entities is wrong and they always need to be flattened? But still, it increases the workload and gets rid of tracking changes through EF when it comes to entity collections.

And a side question, is it better to keep such logic in domain services or rather bring it to another layer?

Answer (score 5):

> DTO -> model -> entity

For the purpose of your question, I'm interpreting this as public contract, domain model, and persistence model (respectively). This may seem obvious but I'm pointing it out because some people use these names in different contexts.

> when it comes to working on a lot of highly nested entities, it is very tedious to track changes, edit and delete them

If you build a skyscraper, you should either not complain about how difficult it is to clean the windows or you should not build skyscrapers so you can have windows that are easier to clean.

Attempt at wit aside, the complexity of your model will generally drive up the complexity of your persistence of said model. That's not inherently bad, it's just a consequence of your design. Whether or not it's the right choice for your use case hinges on several factors that I cannot judge for you (requirements, budget, dev skill level, ...)

> and gets rid of tracking changes through EF when it comes to entity collections.

We reach an interesting fork in the road here, and I have my leg in both. Avoiding a very lengthy discussion on whether EF should be abstracted or used across layer boundaries (opinions are divided), what matter is that you need to see which of these makes sense for your use case.

*If* you decide to not abstract EF and instead let it leak its entities into your domain, then you can rely on the context's change tracking and save yourself some heartache.
However, this comes at the cost of letting EF into your domain. Some think this is acceptable, others do no. I'm relatively pragmatic and consider it a depends-on-the-scenario kind of decision.

*If* you decide that abstracting EF is the right choice for you; then "simple code" is inherently going to have to break the connection to your ORM technology when you're in the domain/business layer. That is the inherent choice you make when you deny EF to leak into your domain.

That being said, you could implement your persistence logic with something that looks at everything coming into the persistence layer, sees if there's an equivalent tracked entity, and if so then *somehow* maps the changes onto that tracked entity *or* shifts the tracking towards the input model rather than the originally tracked entity.
Is this possible? Sure. Is this going to be easy to get right? Unlikely.

I've seen another way around this by defining the domain model as an *interface* rather than a class, thus allowing the opportunity for an EF entity to implement said interface. When done right, this means that you can actually just return your entity (via the interface type) and keep your domain/business logic blissfully unaware what the real class is.
However, this is very difficult to get right and it still doesn't fix the issue for models that created by someone other than the EF context.

> Always this mapping basically one to one, seemed to me a lot of work, which in most cases is unnecessary.

You've struck at the very core of what I'm going to call pro-bad-practice arguments.

Good practice dictates that you do certain things that take extra effort. The idea here is that a little effort now is going to save a lot of effort down the road. However, what is sometimes forgotten is the cost of blanket-implementing these good practice measures and how often they end up being used or not.

However, I can make the same argument the other way. What is sometimes forgotten by the pro-bad-practice proponents is the work that to them seems "obviously needed" that would've been entirely avoided if the design had been better to begin with.

*The [preparedness paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preparedness_paradox) is very relevant to read up on in this context.*

Essentially, you need to estimate how many corners you want to cut, and both overestimating (bad practice) or underestimating (overzealous good practice) is going to waste effort.
This is the part where we get back to "depends on your context". Ask your business whether they'd rather pay an extra cost now (guaranteed) or run a risk of a much bigger cost later down the line (but at the same time not having any cost if the risk is not triggered).

Personally, I have seen too many projects fail by buckling under mountains of technical debt, and I will gladly take the "small effort upfront". I much prefer spending time and effort building clean and elegant code, as opposed to having to fix bugs in a restrictive codebase that's constrained by the technical debt that it carries.

From where I'm sitting, I do not balk at mapping from one data class to another if it helps me cleanly separate the layers of my codebase.

Comment: Great answer, except for *"Ask your business whether they'd rather pay an extra cost now (guaranteed) or run a risk of a much bigger cost later down the line"* because the **business** will always choose "save cost now". Instead, ask for the time you need, look for corners to cut and when they cannot accommodate that timeline. But never, ever, ever tell them they have a choice between cheap now or cheap later. "Now" always wins.

Comment: (still up-voted the answer, though)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
My point is that I am trying to keep the entities relatively simple with a maximum of one level of nesting. And it's just very hard for me to imagine the gain I'll make when I do the mapping between domain and repository. 
In my case, the layers will be separated, but so what? I'm not going to abandon EF. What, besides effort and code complexity will this mapping give me? A greater risk of mistakes?

Comment: @Gersalom: Layer separation (i.e. via mapping) provides the ability for each individual model to evolve without necessarily impacting the other side of that layer. I understand that you say you're not going to abandon EF and I'm fairly certain the odds are in your favor here; but everyone who comes to regret not separating their layers earlier made the same claim that you did; so it remains to be seen whether you'll have been objectively correct or misguided by wanting to avoid upfront effort. I'm not saying that this is the case, I'm saying that I cannot disprove it from where I'm standing.

Comment: @Gersalom: Just as an example, you point out that you are " trying to keep the entities relatively simple with a maximum of one level of nesting". Are you comfortable with that also leading you to be unable to make a more nested domain model? If you don't separate your layers, and you put a cap on how complex you'll allow the persistence entities to be; you've then also put a cap on your domain model. You might not see a problem here, but from experience a little "am I painting myself into a corner?" bell starts ringing.

Comment: @Flater I probably have a big bias when it comes to this. I'm very comfortable working on entities from EF and it's possible that I'm just looking for confirmation that it's not a bad thing.

Comment: @Gersalom: I spent a long time arguing that same point, and I do stand by it in certain cases; but while the point is valid I do now believe that it has limited applicability to specific data driven use cases and less so for domain-driven designs.

Comment: @flater Well, and throwing in such analogies, one could also say that the preparations were bad in advance. Like preparing for a tsunami in Europe. 
Well, and the amount of time saved now, over and over again, could far outweigh the time to correct a possible bug which could take a very long time. 
I know you wrote "it depends" in a nutshell. 
I like to keep things simple, without unnecessary complexity, and as I say, it's possible that confirmation bias is speaking through me.

Comment: @flater Could you please further expand on this? I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Gersalom: EF dictates how your persistence layer is designed. In a codebase where the app is derived from the data it stores (such as a plain CRUD api), it can make sense to have the rest of the app be defined by the entities it serves up. However, when the meat of the app is found in its complex business logic, then the _domain_ is the one driving the design, which EF has no say over, making it harder to justify letting EF run through the domain.

Comment: @Flater And could you please give me some advice in that case. If my domain aggregators define specifications like 'usersWithoutAddedContextSpec' which have includes, wheres, selectors etc typical for EF in them and are used like 'var result = await _repo.ListAsync(new xxxxSpec() ) then I should flip this to the repo as method _repo.ListUsersWithoutAddedContextAsync()? Because I don't see how the specification can continue to exist after separating the EF entities from the domain. This is how Ardalis was using them in his CA template.

Comment: @Gersalom The example code you're referencing has no meaning to me. I'm not attempting to build your codebase from the ground up, I'm giving you architectural advice so that _you_ can then decide how to design your codebase. I'm also not Ardalis, and it's difficult for me to answer what someone else's idea may have been in a context I'm not aware of. However, in this particular case Ardalis (ssmith) actually posted an answer here, and it appears their answer very much aligns with mine in that it's contextual and not universally answerable.

Comment: @Flater ok. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The OP reached out to me via email and perhaps I can assist.

I think @Flater's response is good - the main answer of "it depends" is hard to argue with.

There are a couple of approaches one might use (this is not exhaustive):

1. No DDD. Simplest thing that works.

In this scenario, you don't need rich domain models. Your entities are just bags of properties and you can pass around DbContext wherever you want. The app is simple CRUD and there's no need to overcomplicate it. Clean Architecture might make it more testable but since there's no complex logic to test it, too, may be overkill.

2. There's business complexity - use DDD to tame it.

In this scenario you want to leverage encapsulation in your domain model to model business logic and enforce invariants. That entity's property should only ever have values of 1 to 100? Whenever you add an item to the entity its parent should check if it's still valid via a domain event? These are DDD patterns and approaches.

In this scenario you strive for an infrastructure-independent model of the domain that includes its invariants and business logic, and doesn't know or care about persistence. Then you map these entities to the database using EF Core and Configuration classes as you've seen in my Clean Architecture template and sample(s).

One key pattern you don't mention but which sounds crucial to your question is [Aggregates](https://deviq.com/domain-driven-design/aggregate-pattern) . I suggest you spend some time reviewing this pattern as I think it may hold the answers to your question. The short version is, the aggregate is the thing you save - all of it or none of it. It's also the thing that checks for invariants at the collection level - not individual item - level. The sum of all purchase order items shouldn't exceed the PO amount? Aggregate responsibility. All of the emails under the MailingList entity should be unique? Aggregate responsibility. Use aggregates appropriately and your life will be much easier.

Finally, if you have more than 2 layers of nesting in your aggregates, you may want to rethink your design. It's not impossible, but it does add a lot of complexity. More often than not you can get away with just key properties rather than navigation properties for some dependencies and avoid deeply nested aggregates. More on this in my [DDD Fundamentals course](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/domain-driven-design-fundamentals).

Comment: I reviewed the course you mentioned but it doesn't cover my query. It seems dbcontext is also used at the controller level as you indicated. 
I work with aggregates and wonder if an entity should be converted to a model, processed by the aggregate, then remapped to the entity for saving? 
Like you mentioned MailingListEntity and List<MailEntity>, should I create corresponding models MailingListModel with List<MailModel>, perform operations, then map and save like this:
MailingListModel -> MailingListEntity -> save/change
and separetly
List<MailModel> -> List<MailEntity> -> save/change?

Comment: Besides, then the specifications from your library lose usability. Specifications are, so to speak, directly plugged into the repository, also from your library, because the repository expects them to get data from the database. I can use model insted of entity there as well but how should they be used, especially if I have some selector? After adding entity<-> model mapping I have to move the specification from the domain(aggregate) to the repository layer and do practically for each specification a separate method. No sense.

Comment: It would probably help if you shared some code or a Gist or something at this point. In my applications the specifications live in the domain. They never live in the infrastructure project with the repository implementations. If you need DTOs (I think what you're calling models - they're all models, though) for your application layer, I typically put these in their own layer or the UI layer. Mapping to them happens either in the UI or (if I have one) in application layer. Specs can do the mapping but I use them for this rarely (usually only if perf requires it).

Comment: No no, you have misunderstood me. By models I meant domain models. I don't know if examples are necessary, because my program draws very heavily from your examples. I really like your specifications and repositories.  I have the specifications in the domain and it's nice for me to use them. 
With DTOs I have no problem. The problem is EF leakage into the domain. The entities in the domain that serve as domain models are also data models in your case. And a lot of people are in favour of separating the domain from the EF completely.

Comment: In your case the DbSets are on the same classes that you use in the domain. And it was recommended to me to separate the data entities from the domain models. But I don't like it too much, I notice the problems but they seem worth it to me.
After the separation I would not be able to use the specifications from the domain level in the current way (as you also use in your examples) or it would be difficult.

Comment: One of the problems, for example, is calling SaveChanges. It can happen that by EF tracking changes, we save changes that we would not want to save. It is a pity that EF does not have the possibility to save a change only for the entity given to it, only for the whole context.

Comment: Yes it's true there are some minor violations of Persistence Ignorance (PI) on domain models when using EF Core code first directly with them. For instance, sometimes you must have a private parameterless constructor that you otherwise never use, so that EF can use it. And yes SaveChanges will save *all* changes even if you have multiple entities or aggregates changing, only some of which are "ready" to be saved at the moment. All true, but still it works great 99+% of the time so I typically accept these tradeoffs.